# Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

i am using spring 3, and i have two beans of view scope:

**1- Bean1:**

```
@Component("bean1")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean1 {

@Autowired
private Bean2 bean2;

}
```

**2- Bean2:**

```
@Component("bean2")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean2 {

@Autowired
private Bean1 bean1;

}
```

the view is a custom scope:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="${project.groupId}.utils.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and here's the code for the custom view scope:

```
public class ViewScope implements Scope {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getViewRoot().getViewMap();

        if (viewMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return viewMap.get(name);
        } else {
            Object object = objectFactory.getObject();
            viewMap.put(name, object);

            return object;
        }
    }

    public Object remove(String name) {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap()
                .remove(name);
    }

    public String getConversationId() {
        return null;
    }

    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
        // Not supported
    }

    public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

when opening the page that uses both beans, i get the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agencyBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
    at com.myapp.utils.ViewScope.get(ViewScope.java:20)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
    at com.xeno.xecamp.webManagement.utils.ViewScope.get(ViewScope.java:20)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:244)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2508)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2139)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2087)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:244)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.Jsf2FlowApplication.publishEvent(Jsf2FlowApplication.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

please advise how to fix this exception.

**EDIT**: i tried to use the **setter injection** as referenced in the answer here

[Understanding Spring context initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632596/understanding-spring-context-initialization-order)

but it doesn's work too.

**1- Bean1:**

```
@Component("bean1")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean1 {


private Bean2 bean2;

@Autowired
public void setBean2 (Bean2 bean2) {
    this.bean2= bean2;
}

}
```

**2- Bean2:**

```
@Component("bean2")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean2 {


private Bean1 bean1;

@Autowired
public void setBean1 (Bean1 bean1) {
    this.bean1= bean1;
}

}
```

but it gives me the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.myapp.beans.Bean1] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: To resolve problem with circular dependency you should remove one autowired dependency and set it manually later (with @PostConstruct or something similar). See 'sinuhepop' example below.

Comment: This article helps who is looking for a answer. http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The Spring Framework uses a special logic for resolving these kinds of circular dependencies with singleton beans. But this won't apply to other scopes. There is no elegant way of breaking this circular dependency, but a clumsy option could be this one:

```
@Component("bean1")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean1 {

    @Autowired
    private Bean2 bean2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        bean2.setBean1(this);
    }
}

@Component("bean2")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean2 {

    private Bean1 bean1;

    public void setBean1(Bean1 bean1) {
        this.bean1 = bean1;
    }
}
```

Anyway, circular dependencies are usually a symptom of bad design. You would think again if there is some better way of defining your class dependencies.

Comment: Agree, DI or not, circular dependencies are a pain to maintain and should be avoided.

Comment: There are certain cases where circular dependencies make perfect sense. Like the delegate pattern in Cocoa. A view controller acts as the delegate for a view.

Comment: I thought the point of beans and components and configs and services was to make code easier to reason about, not force you to some hierarchical design.

Comment: Ugly - but we love it :)

Answer (score 139):

I think you could use Spring's

> @Lazy

annotation on one of the autowired fields to break circular dependency.

*I'm not sure if this works/exists in mentioned Spring version.*

Comment: For me it assigns the bean to the Exception and continues!

Comment: @Lazy is also know to create circular dependencies

Comment: I think perhaps @Lazy doesn't create circular dependencies, it just allows them to exist, which results in more of them being created, because devs never learn of the circular dependencies they've created.

Answer (score 25):

In my case, I was defining a bean and autowiring it in the constructor of the same class file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    private MyBean myBean;

    public MyApplication(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

My solution was to move the bean definition to another class file.

```
@Configuration
public CustomConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like the error message could be improved when this happens

Answer (score 19):

***IMPORTANT:** Read the EDIT at the end.*

I also encountered this Exception after I upgraded Spring to 2.6.6 (this may or may not be relevant).

```
ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Keep in mind that my class was extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**. This is a configuration class using **@Configuration** & **@EnableWebSecurity** annotation.

Anyway the solution that worked for me was this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71980044/

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ..."some code"...
}
```

After the change, that method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ..."same code"...
}
```

So I've just changed the **@Autowired** to **@Override** and renamed the method to **configure()**.

***EDIT:***

This change brought some unexpected problems for me. My configuration allows multiple AuthenticationProviders. Also there are multiple sub classes that extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter defined in my SecurityConfig class.

***The problem:*** in most (well, actually all) cases the wrong AuthenticationProvider was called.

***The sollution:*** I had to go back to **@Autowired** and **configureGlobal** :/
The circular dependency can be "ignored" by adding the following flag in your **application.yml** spring configuration:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-circular-references: true
```

Comment: So, you're allowing circular dependency through application config? Clearly, this is a design issue and should be resolved by amending your code.

Comment: There is no circular dependency in my code whatsoever. I reckon that might come through some spring dependencies or something else "deeper down" in the company's lib stack.

Answer (score 12):

My solution was to move the bean definition to another class of configuration

```
@Configuration
public class EncoderConfig {
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use like that, with both `@Autowired` and `@Lazy` annotations:

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
ServiceClass serviceClass;
```

Credits to @FaZoM.

Answer (score 5):

i encountered this error in quite a stupid way

```
@Autowired
// private Bean bean;

public void myMethod() {
  return;
}
```

what happened is that I commented a line for some reason and left the annotation which made spring think that the method needs to be autowired

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way to deal with circular dependencies is to use setter injection.

I tried the setter injection code that you posted, and it worked for me.  I would imagine the reason you are getting the exception is because Bean1 and Bean2 are in the com.myapp.beans package, and you don't have component scanning enabled for that package.

You'd need to add the following to your spring configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bullethq.accounts.web"/>
```

or move the beans to a package which is being automatically scanned by Spring.

Comment: Msaleh is using setter injection in both cases (as opposed to constructor argument injection). Your test worked probably because you  used singleton scoped beans.

Comment: I know it's 7 years late, but after 6 weeks debugging circular references caused by setter injection, I've got some verbiage that would make a sailor blush to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding the following in application file :

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I change one method in a class which extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  and it was ...

```
 @Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    
}
```

to this

```
  @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    
}
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using constructor injection with @Lazy annotation
the circular dependency was caused by CustomerContactService Bean so I
added @Lazy for it in the constructor

```
    public AuthenticationFacadeImpl(AppUserService appUserService,
                                @Lazy CustomerContactService customerContactService) {
    this.appUserService = appUserService;
    this.customerContactService = customerContactService;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Resource annotation on field level also could be used to declare look up at runtime

Answer (score 0):

**1. Disable Non-Test Security-Config for tests**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("!test")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

**2. Add Test-Security Config in Test-Folder**

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("**/*").anonymous();
  }
}
```

**3. Add TestConfig to Integration Test**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestSecurityConfig.class)
public class IntegrationTest { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting below error

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?**
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]

I solved by adding @Lazy

```
**@Lazy**
@Autowired()
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Bean1` references `Bean2`, and `Bean2` references `Bean1`, the best way to solve it is to introduce third bean `Bean3`, where some blocking interactions between `Bean1` and `Bean2` are handled.
That way you effectively solve circular dependency and not avoiding it with workaround.
The trick is to dereference `Bean1` and `Bean2` in one direction, not necessary both, just enough to solve circular dependency on one side. In the picture below `Bean1` lost reference to `Bean2`, while `Bean2` still has reference to `Bean1`, then `Bean3` holds references to both `Bean1` and `Bean2`, where logic from `Bean1` is relocated:

[image: circular dependency solution]

Answer (score -1):

In general, the most appropriated way to avoid this problem, (also because of better Mockito integration in JUnit) is to use the Setter/Field Injection as described at https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring and at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

```
@Component("bean1")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean1 {
    private Bean2 bean2;

    @Autowired
    public void setBean2(Bean2 bean2) {
        this.bean2 = bean2;
    }
}

@Component("bean2")
@Scope("view")
public class Bean2 {
    private Bean1 bean1;

    @Autowired
    public void setBean1(Bean1 bean1) {
        this.bean1 = bean1;
    }
}
```