# Overriding bean definition for bean 'X': replacing [Generic bean Y]

Tags: spring-batch

I have the configuration like below:

```
batch:job id="reconciliationJob" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="true"
```

and during application context startup I receive something like this in the log:

> [INFO] [] [] Overriding bean definition for bean 'reconciliationJob': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParserJobFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]

How can I solve this overriding problem?

Comment: is there a way to get rid of these log messages?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error. My problem was that I marked the class with `@Service` then in one of the `@Configuration` classes I created a `@Bean` out of it with the same name as the class.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when Spring parses the same `applicationContext.xml` twice.

This can happen when for example your have duplicate/overriding `<context-param>` imports in your `WEB.xml`.

To solve the issue leave only the root `applicationContext.xml` there and remove the children.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error, is only an [INFO] and is a substitution done by Spring; you can see something similar about "step" scoped beans.
For example, if you have a bean marked as

```
<bean id="myBean" class="path.to.beanClass" scope="step" />
```

this will be replaced by a bean with name `scopedTarget.myBean`.
Lookup at [StepScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/StepScope.html) doc and source

Comment: Due to this duplicate bean definition, server wont start properly for few cases. It leads to bean creation exception - **Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?**


Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008714/requested-bean-is-currently-in-creation-is-there-an-unresolvable-circular-refer


Two reasons for this:
1. Circular dependency
2. Duplicate bean definition

FYI @przodownikPracy

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar and I just changed the name of the class and it worked. Still can't figure out why. I'll update if I understand it better.

But start with changing the bean's class name.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it using `dependency:analyze` in run maven -> goals. I found unused dependencies in my pom and I removed the unused dependencies.

Note: take care when removing the dependencies because the result of `dependency:analyze` it is not secure .