# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
package ro.contabilitateexpert.AccountExpert.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I have the following error :
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

How can i solve it?

Comment: Well... is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: Need to add more code from my project to clear this out?

Comment: no, only 1 little clarification: why there is no `@Configuration` on your `@EnableWebSecurity` ..adapter?

Comment: No is not, i`m trying to learn spring so if you can help me with an advice will be great

Comment: I think it should be just `configure` instead of `configureGlobal` plus not `@Autowired` but `@Overrides` there. Also, `@Configuration` is missing indeed.

Comment: Thank you  
@AlexeyVeleshko It worked

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko, could you post an answer with the code as it would look, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After i changed to configure instead of configureGlobal with @Overrides and deleted @Autowired
Added @Configuration
Now the code is working,

Thanks to  Alexey Veleshko

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pretty useless answer since one can not understand nor reproduce what you have done.

Comment: Can you post the code when it works too please?

Answer (score 16):

More detailed solution:

code before:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

changing @Autowired and function name

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package ro.contabilitateexpert.AccountExpert.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I edited the code; this should work. What did I do? I changed the name of the `configureGlobal` method to configure and used the `@Override` annotation instead of `@Autowired`. The @Autowired method, `configureGlobal`, somehow was also using the `SecurityConfig` bean, which was internally being created (of course, it was being created; what do we think made the call to the `configureGlobal` method)

Answer (score 0):

**When migrating spring and other dependencies, including spring security, I have encountered this issue.**

```
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   FrameworkContextFilter defined in class path resource [com/company/frame/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
      ↓
   mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]
      ↓
   org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration (field private java.util.List org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.configurers)
      ↓
   oauthConfig.AuthorizationServerConfiguration (field org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.company.frame.config.OauthConfig$AuthorizationServerConfiguration.authenticationManager)
┌─────┐
|  securityConfig (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder com.company.frame.config.SecurityConfig.passwordEncoder)
└─────┘
```

**Following is the solution which survived my troubleshooting.**

```
@Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    | 
    V
@Autowired @Lazy private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

and

@Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    |
    V 
@Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
```

Answer (score -1):

spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
add this property in application.properties file

or add below in application.yaml file
spring:
main:
allow-circular-references: true

Comment: You could do so, but you should definitely avoid doing such stuff. Allowing circular dependencies brings inconsistency to your system.